# Черный экран после установки ХР

Tags: windows

В общем уже мозг сломал и пальцы отбил: На старом компе стояло 2ОС ХР и UBUNTU 10.04,так как завёл себе ноут, домашние попросили убрать убунту и заодно переустановить ХР. Диск был отформатирован и была произведена установка. Установка прошла нормально всё копировалось всё устанавливалось, ну как обычно. Но далее загрузка системы начинается появляется логотип ХР, почемуто 2 раза моргает, затем черный экран с мышкой. Попробовал ещё 2 другие сборки- результат одинаковый, причём на ноуте всё это работаетю Попробовал восстановить MBR, стало грузиться до логотипа сборки, причём комп то не висит- мышка то бегает. Решил опять поставить убунту, в надежде, что GRUB сможет запустить  ХР, результат- убунта прекрасно работает, груб видит  ХР, но с запуском тоже самое- черный экран.

Answer (score 1):

Если появляется логотип при загрузке, то дело не в загрузчике. Скорее проблема с системными файлами или драйверами. Надо попробовать запуститься в безопасном режиме. При загрузке нажать F8. В появившемся меню выбрать безопасную загрузку. Если не работает после нескольких переустановок, то это похоже на аппаратную проблему. Я бы еще попробовал установить Windows 7 и обнулить БИОС.

Еще надо попробовать в безопасном режиме удалить драйвера устройств. У меня на ноутбуке была аналогичная проблема. После удаления драйвера видеокарты система стала загружаться. Возможно проблема в другом устройстве, тогда надо удалить драйвер этого устройства.

Можно еще посмотреть протокол загрузки. Чтобы его включить надо в корне диска С в файле boot.ini добавить раздел /bootlog. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833721). Там внизу есть пример текста этого файла. Еще можно попробовать параметр /basevideo, если проблема с видеокартой.

Comment: В безопасном режиме заходит, попробую обнулить БИОС, хотя уверен, что он ни причём, ну и 7 попробую, хотя на этом компе она толком работать не будет Р4 и 1.5 Гига оперативки

Comment: Частой причиной черного экрана являются вирусы. Но с ваших слов были попытки установки трех дистрибутивов и форматировался диск. Значит вирусы ни при чем. Остается две причины: железо и софт (драйвера). С БИОС-ом были какие-то проблемы, надо было отключать какую-то настройку.Если в безопасном режиме заходит, то можно включить логирование загрузки, чтобы понять на каком месте останавливается загрузка.

Comment: то можно включить логирование загрузки- как это сделать?

Comment: Сбросил БИОС, как и ожидал никакого эффекта

Comment: Удалять драйверы пробовали? А с протоколированием загрузки получилось?

Comment: да в реестр залез, но честно не представляю даже что удалять- диспетчер устройств говорит, что всё работает корректно. А вот как  запротоколировать загрузку не знаю, но хотелось бы узнать

Comment: В диспетчере устройств можно попробовать удалить драйвер в пункте Видеоадаптеры.  По протоколированию загрузки я уже изменил ответ выше. Там есть ссылка на описание с примером.

Answer (score 0):

При первом старте винда ставит драва для видяхи. Есть опенсурсные дрова они то как раз там. Если в диспетчере устрв. есть драйвер для видяхи NVIDIA или ATI нужно удалить что бы было стандартный драйвер.

Comment: В общем проблему не решил, но тем не менее 7 максимальная (сборка) пошла.Подвожу итог встают и нормально функционируют  Ubuntu и 7, а ХР по не понятным причинам устанавливается , но наотрез отказывается запускаться. Драйвера вряд ли виноваты, биос  сбрасывал, MBR восстанавливал, осталось только отредактировать boot/ini, но наверное оставлю 7, хоть и не люблю её